# How to control another list of elements in between another list

Tags: jquery

I have a list in function that are hidden and a click of a button unhides them. There's another list in between items that does the same thing: hidden until a button is clicked. Here's an example:

- 1
- 2
- 3a
- 3b
- 3c
- 4
- 5

It works fine until the end of 3c. When I click a button to continue, everything disappears. I'm trying to find a way to continue to unhide a list in the first list when changing to the second list.

My code: Click on 'single next' to advance. When 3a appears, click 'multi next' until 3c. When click on 'single next' after 3c, it disappears. 4 is suppose to show then 5

```js
$("#multi-single-next").click(function () { 
  var index = $('.pagnation').find('li:visible').index();
  if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
    index = index == 0 ? 0 : (index - 1);
  } else {
    var totalLiElem = $('.pagnation').find('li').length
    index = (index == (totalLiElem - 1)) ? (totalLiElem - 1) : (index + 1);
  }
  $('.pagnation').find('li:visible').fadeToggle("fast", "linear", function() {
    $('.pagnation').find('li:eq(' + index + ')').fadeToggle(550, "linear");
  });
});
$('.pagnation-2 li:gt(0)').hide();
$('#multi-next-multi-item').click(function() {
    var last = $('.pagnation-2').children('li:visible:last');
    last.nextAll(':lt(1)').fadeToggle('slow').show();
    last.next().prevAll().fadeToggle('slow').hide();
});
```

```css
.pagnation li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .pagnation li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="multi-single-next" class="button">Single next</button>
<button id="multi-next-multi-item" class="button">Multi item</button>
<ul class="pagnation">
<li class="single-data-item"><div class="data-item">1</div></li>
<li class="single-data-item"><div class="data-item">2</div></li>
<li class="single-data-item has-multi-items"><ul class="pagnation-2">
    <li>3a</li>
    <li>3b</li>
    <li>3c</li>
</li></ul>
<li class="single-data-item"><div class="data-item">4</div></li>
<li class="single-data-item"><div class="data-item">5</div></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want?

I remove index and use class `active` instead as current index.
Next LI can be simple simply showed with using [.next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) sibling.

```
$('#multi-single-next').click(function() {
    let $item;

    if(!$('ul.pagnation li.single-data-item.active').length) {
        $item = $('ul.pagnation li.single-data-item').first();
    }
    else {
        $prev = $('ul.pagnation li.single-data-item.active');
        $item = $prev.next();

        if(!$prev.next().length) {
            $prev.removeClass('active');
            $prev.hide();
            return;
        }

        $prev.removeClass('active');
        $prev.hide();
    }

    $item.addClass('active');
    $item.show();

    // sub items
    $('ul.pagnation-2 li').removeClass('active');
    if($item.hasClass('has-multi-items')) {
        const $sub = $item.find('ul li').first();
        $sub.addClass('active');
        $sub.show();
    }
});


$('#multi-next-multi-item').click(function() {
    const $item = $('ul.pagnation-2 li.active');
    const $next = $item.next();

    $item.removeClass('active');
    $item.hide();

    $next.addClass('active');
    $next.show();
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zshf790o/1/)

Comment: It's a good start but you have the 3's (3a,3b,3c) show up as one and I had them show up as separate.

Comment: what you mean separate? So I don't understand what you want. If you click single you show first item, if contain multi then click to multi and show sub items. Please clarify your question. Also your code die after 3a not 3c.