# How to show a button depending on if there another item in a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problems finding a solution for my code. [I asked for help on how to continue click on a list if there's another list inside the list and how to switch between those lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58575093/how-to-control-another-list-of-elements-in-between-another-list/58575510?noredirect=1#comment103474184_58575510) and I've got it to work but the problem I'm having is if the second list is either the last item or if there.

Basically, it looks like this:

```
<button id="multi-single-next" class="button">Single next</button>
<button id="multi-next-multi-item" class="button">Multi item</button>
<button id="hide" class="button">Hide</button>
<ul class="multi-items">
<li class="single-data-item"><div class="data-item">1</div></li>
<li class="single-data-item"><div class="data-item">2</div></li>
<li class="single-data-item has-multi-items">
<ul class="pagnation-2">
   <li>3a</li>
   <li>3b</li>
   <li>3c</li>
</ul></li>
<li class="single-data-item"><div class="data-item">4</div></li>
<li class="single-data-item"><div class="data-item">5</div></li>
```

And the way I have it setup is that went the button switches from `.multi-items` to `.pagnation-2`, when it gets to the end of that list, it doesn't go back to `.multi-items` to continue the list.

What would be the best way to check if either the second list (`.pagnation-2`) is the last item (I.E. no `<li>` after `.pagnation-2`) or if the first list continues (I.E. there are `<li>` after `.pagnation-2`)?

Here's a working example of my problem:

```js
$('#multi-single-next').click(function() {
  let $item;

  if(!$('ul.multi-items li.single-data-item.active').length) {
      $item = $('ul.multi-items li.single-data-item').first();
  }
  else {
      $prev = $('ul.multi-items li.single-data-item.active');
      $item = $prev.next();

      if(!$prev.next().length) {
          $prev.removeClass('active');
          $prev.delay(1).fadeOut(300);
          return;
      }

      $prev.removeClass('active');
      $prev.delay(1).fadeOut(300);
  }

  $item.addClass('active');
  $item.delay(300).fadeIn(450);
  
  // sub items
  $('ul.pagnation-2 li').removeClass('active');
  if($item.hasClass('has-multi-items')) {
      const $sub = $item.find('ul li').first();
      $sub.addClass('active');
      $sub.delay(200).fadeIn(250);
      $('#multi-single-next').css('display','none');
      $('#multi-next-multi-item').css('display','block');
      }
});


$('#multi-next-multi-item').click(function() {
  const $item = $('ul.pagnation-2 li.active');
  const $next = $item.next();

  $item.removeClass('active');
  $item.hide();

  $next.addClass('active');
  $next.show();
});
```

```css
.multi-items li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .multi-items li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  #multi-next-multi-item {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="multi-single-next" class="button">Single next</button>
<button id="multi-next-multi-item" class="button">Multi item</button>
<ul class="multi-items">
<li class="single-data-item active"></li>
<li class="single-data-item"><div class="data-item">1</div></li>
<li class="single-data-item"><div class="data-item">2</div></li>
<li class="single-data-item has-multi-items"><ul class="pagnation-2">
    <li>3a</li>
    <li>3b</li>
    <li>3c</li>
</ul></li>
<li class="single-data-item"><div class="data-item">3</div></li>
<li class="single-data-item"><div class="data-item">4</div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `length` of next `li` if it does exists.

**Solution**

```
$('#multi-next-multi-item').click(function() {
  const $item = $('ul.pagnation-2 li.active');
  const $next = $item.next();

  //Check if last item
  const $lastItem = $('ul.pagnation-2 li.active').next().length;

  $item.removeClass('active');
  $item.hide();

  if($lastItem == 0){

      //Get the parent
      const $li_parent = $item.parent().parent();

      const $single_next = $li_parent.next();

      $li_parent.removeClass('active');
      $li_parent.hide();

      $single_next.addClass('active');
      $single_next.show();
      $('#multi-single-next').css('display','block');
      $('#multi-next-multi-item').css('display','none');
  }else{
      $next.addClass('active');
      $next.show();
  }

});
```